# launching gps setting screen in android

Tags: android

The following code is launching gps setting screen in samsung device but in htc device it is launching security screen of setting.How can i write code so that it will launch gps screen independent of the devices.Please help is there any alternative solution

```
final ComponentName toLaunch = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.SecuritySettings");
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setComponent(toLaunch);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `setComponent()` and `addCategory()` calls and see if that helps. You should not be using those in any case, particularly the `ComponentName` that hard-wires in invalid package and class names.

Comment: Worked for me to, for anyone else who will need to use it:

Answer (score -1):

I think this code is helpful for you

`Intent intent1 = new Intent();
    intent1.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                                "com.android.settings.SecuritySettings");
                context.startActivity(intent1);`

Comment: This doesn't work on all devices (e.g. JellyBean/4.1) since the settings for geo have been moved around a bit.