# Find class to use with ComponentName class in Android

Tags: android

I have a single widget that call another application, here is the most important part of the code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", 
"com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctxt.startActivity( intent);
```

The important part is

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
```

This call the wifi settings in android, but I found this code in a web site, I want to know how I can call the data roaming and other settings in the system, where I can see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.android.settings` is the name of the package. If you go [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/a9125d4d59bb3293dd1c92189bec3d0ab9e71d52/src/com/android/settings) you can find all the settings available in this package. The roaming settings are in package `com.android.phone` <s>- see [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-mobile-data-setting)</s>.

EDIT : it [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7024631/281545) that using package names is not portable. Your best bet is to use :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));
```

The list of intents is in the [Settings class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

You [may also need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13385550/281545) to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your intent