# Opening specific part of system settings from app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a shortcut from my app which opens the storage part of system settings, (which works perfectly), but if the settings app is already running, and was last left from say the display settings, you don't get directed to the storage settings, but the display settings, when pressing the shortcut.

Is there a way to force opening storage settings, or say close (if not closed) the settings app, before trying to launch the storage?

I am using the intent `android.settings.INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS` to start the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the following flag on your intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```