# How to start "settings" application?

Tags: java, android

When the user running my application, I want my application forward the user to the settings -> location & security -> Use wireless networks. How am I going to achieve that?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you found on google?

Comment: Look at the top answer here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-can-i-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android

Comment: ok, thank, cant imagine that just one line will do: startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start Wireless Settings as:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.WirelessSettings");
intent.setComponent(cName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: If you want to launch only Wifi Settings then use `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));`

Comment: what's the difference with your answer (which might be non portable : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7024631/281545) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```